# Need help figuring out why my dice game counter isn't accurate

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is the code that I have built for the dice game i made. I need it to display the number of wins and the number of losses once i quit the game. Everything is running smoothly, but it is only counting the last result currently. any ideas why?

```
import random

   def roll_dice():
      winner = 0
      loser = 0
      roll = (random.randint(1,6))
      roll2 = (random.randint(1,6))
      print(roll,"  "roll2)
      if roll == roll2:
        print("Winner!")
        winner += 1
      else:
        print("Loser!")
        loser += 1
      play_again = input("Would you like to play again?")

      if play_again == "yes":
        roll_dice()

      else:
        print("You won " , winner , "times")
        print("You lost ", loser , "times")
        quit

   def main():

     game_start = input("Would you like to roll the dice?")
     if game_start == 'yes':
        roll_dice()

     else:
        print("too bad")

   if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Please add the current output and the desired output

Comment: You're resetting `winner` and `loser` every time you execute `roll_dice()`. Change those variables to global variables (defined in main or outside of a function) and then write `global winner, loser` at the top of `roll_dice`.

Comment: `winner` and `loser`, will reset on every call to the function `roll_dice`, making them global or passing them to the function on every call would help, or you can use a class and make them the class variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is happening because you are variables winner and loser are local variables and are re-initialized to zero every time roll_dice() is called. You can either have winner and loser as global variables or pass them as arguments to your function. See below with global variable*

```
import random

winner = 0
loser = 0

def roll_dice():
  global winner, loser
  roll = (random.randint(1,6))
  roll2 = (random.randint(1,6))
  print(roll,"  ",roll2)
  if roll == roll2:
    print("Winner!")
    winner += 1
  else:
    print("Loser!")
    loser += 1
  play_again = input("Would you like to play again?")

  if play_again == "yes":
    roll_dice()

  else:
    print("You won " , winner , "times")
    print("You lost ", loser , "times")
    quit

def main():

 game_start = input("Would you like to roll the dice?")
 if game_start == 'yes':
    roll_dice()

 else:
    print("too bad")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***Also I would like to point out that you should not use recursion here as it can cause a stack overflow error. looping would be a better option.***

Comment: thank you, I did not realize it was initializing the variables each time but explaining it that way helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is because `winner` and `loser` are local variables scoped to a call of `roll_dice`.

Each call would instantiate a new variable `loser` and `winner` and the instance goes away with the return of the function.

More here [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

One dirty fix to your problem would be to make `winner` and `loser` variables in global scope.

A cleaner solution would be to restructure your code to make `roll_dice` return the count of `winner` and `loser` as a tuple.

Comment: i am going with the dirty fix for now but i will look into how to incorporate the cleaner solution for future code to ensure my programs are efficient. thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call your `function` (because you made it as recursion), the variable of `winner` and `loser` become `zero`. I think you need to change your `function` in `def roll_dice()`. It's better to use `looping` as stated by @ashutoshy.and01.

Also, you make the player as a winner if only the number on both dices equal, otherwise a loser even the player's dice number is greater than the computer's.

```
def roll_dice():
    winner = 0
    loser = 0
    play_again = "yes"
    while play_again == "yes":
        roll = (random.randint(1,6))
        roll2 = (random.randint(1,6))
        print(str(roll),"  ",end=str(roll2))
        if roll >= roll2:
            print(" Winner!")
            winner += 1
        else:
            print(" Loser!")
            loser += 1
        play_again = input("Would you like to play again?")
    print("You won " , winner , "times")
    print("You lost ", loser , "times")
    quit
```

Comment: this is much cleaner code and also fixes my problem without having to make 'winner' and 'loser' global variables so thanks so much

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark the answer as accepted if you feel the code helps you. Cheers..